# Find $\text{Im}(T)$ if $T:P_2(\mathbb R)\to P_2(\mathbb R)$ and $T(f(x)) = 2f''(1)x^2+f'(1)x+f(2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I don't know how I'm supposed to do this.

$\text{Im}(T) = \text{span}${$T(1), T(x), T(x^2)$}

Is this right?
I am not sure how to do $T(1), T(x), T(x^2)$ since i have numbers in brackets already instead of $x$. Which part I need to substitute for $1$ or $x$ or $x^2$?

I have result and it should be {$1,2+x,4+2x+4x^2$}.

Maybe like this:

$T(1) = 2\cdot(1)''x^2+(1)'x+1 = 1$

How do I do it for $T(x^2)$?

Comment: To be fair, the notation here is rather bad and informal.  There appears to be frequent conflation between functions $f$ and what said functions map an input to, $f(x)$.  The "$1$" in "$T(1)$" for instance is in reference to the constant function $f$ such that $f(x)=1$ for all $x$.  Similarly, the "$x$" in "$T(x)$" appears to be the function $g$ such that $g(x)=x$.  Technically $g$ and $g(x)$ are not the same types of objects... the one is an element of $P_2$ while the other given a value of $x$ is an element of $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you did correct.

For $T(x)$, you get

$$T(x)=2\cdot x''\cdot x^2+x'\cdot x+2=0+x+2=x+2$$

Similarly, you can compute $T(x^2)$.

Comment: Why is 2 at the end 2⋅x′′⋅x2+x′⋅x+2?

Comment: because $f(x)=x$, so $f(2)=2$

Comment: Thank you so much for kindness and patience.

Comment: When i do it for $x^2$, I get $6x^2+2$... 
$T(X^2) = 2*(x^2)'' * x^2 + (x^2)' * x + 2= 2*2*x^2+2*x*x+2$

Comment: No, you did incorrect, what is $f(x)$ in your case?

Comment: I tried to do x^2 just like in previous case for 1 and x.
like this $T(x)=2⋅x′′⋅x2+x′⋅x+2=0+x+2=x+2$

Comment: note the definition: $T(f(x)) = 2f''(1)x^2+f'(1)x+f(2)$, where is your $f''(1), f'(1)$ and $ f(2)$?

Comment: I just realised my mistake...
$T(x^2) = 2*(x^2)''(1)*x^2+(x^2)'(1)*x + (x^2)(2) = 2*2*x^2 + 2x + 4 = 4*x^2 + 2x + 4$

Comment: yes, that is correct!